# Find out what other websites are open in a customer's browser

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is it feasible to find out what other websites are open in a person's browser through your website.

For example, let say I have a website named abc.com and before opening my website customer have xyz.com and cfd.com already open in his browser in separate tabs. Now if that person opens my website abc.com then by some means I can fetch details about what other websites are open in person's browser, in this case xyz.com & cfd.com.

I am interested to know, does browser's offer some way? Or is it feasible to achieve by some means through Javascript?

Comment: No. VERY big breach of privacy! Only way is to write a plugin that can access all pages

Comment: @mplungjan: plug in as such ? just curious to know if google, firefox will allow such extensions or plugins to be installed on respective browsers.

Comment: Most plugins can access what they want it seems

Comment: @mplungjan Can plugins record this data and send it to their server? Isn't this a privacy breach as well? Does browser does any safety check before making any plugin available to the public?

Comment: I assume they check. But yes they can and do record and send.

Answer (score 0):

No. This is impossible. It would be a terrible privacy invasion otherwise. Browsers have [gone to some lengths to prevent this sort of information from leaking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector).

Comment: In fact if you find a way to do this, and tell the browser makers, they will probably pay you money. Google for instance will pay up to $4000 for an information-leak bug in Chrome

Comment: @AndrewMcGuinness That is a great motivation to hack around :)